# Where is AWS IOT MQTT Topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot

I have a question in context of the previous question asked on this URL ([Dynamically create AWS IoT topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766686/dynamically-create-aws-iot-topic/50748904#50748904)).... I understand that AWS IoT (MQTT) creates topic automatically, if it doesn't exist. But where will I be able to see all existing MQTT topics created by AWS IOT? These topics are not showing up under list of SNS topics? I'm using AWS IoT SDK for Python and created a topic named 'Temperature' through my python script and posted some message on it. My subscriber program is able to get messages from Temperature topic but I'm not able to see this Temperature topic in AWS console, not even in SNS topic list. 
Also, is AWS SNS Topic is same as AWS IoT MQTT topic?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In MQTT, there is no need to create a topic for pub/sub operations. You can use any topic directly if you want.

And therefore you cannot see the topics which are created by AWS IoT.(since there was no creation of topic in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

Topics exist under policy validation like below screenshot

[image]